# Arrow keys don't work when running Visual Studio Code by X11 ssh forwarding

Tags: visual-studio-code

I install VSCode in a Linux VM which is running on VirtualBox and is managed by Vagrant. When I open VSCode from host by ssh X11 forwarding, key mapping is in a mess -- arrow keys, home/end/delete keys don't work.

I've test it on MacOS host (X server is XQuartz) and Win7 host (with MobaXterm's built-in X server), both have issue. On MacOS it's even worse, some alphabets are mapped incorrect.

Arrow keys work fine on other application over X11 forwarding. So I suspect that it should be related to VSCode.

I had read VSCode document about [key binding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), but couldn't find any clue.

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode 1.11, you may be running into this issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24107

I believe the latest insiders 1.12 builds should have a fix. In the current VSCode 1.11 release, you should also be able to set `"keyboard.dispatch": "keyCode"` to restore the previous keyboard handling logic

Please [let us know](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if you still are running into any issues with keybindings in the latest 1.12 insiders builds